# how can two arrays be compared to return a match with python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a dataset1 in this format

```
 ['tyuri:12345', 'hsksfd:58380', 'shskfks:49539']
```

and another dataset2 in this format

```
 ['12345', '442342', '8053308']
```

i want to compare dataset1 with dataset2 and have it return

```
 tyuri:12345
```

I know about using set().intersection() to compare two arrays and return exact match. How would I implement comparing these two arrays to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a = ['tyuri:12345', 'hsksfd:58380', 'shskfks:49539']
b = ['12345', '442342', '8053308']
new_a = [i for i in a if any(i.endswith(c) for c in b)]
```

Output:

```
['tyuri:12345']
```

In `new_a`, a list comprehension is used to find all elements that have a trailing digit that exists in `b`. To find those values, the `any()` function is used to determine if one or more trailing values, found by the `endswith()` method, are contained in `b`.

Comment: this works, can you please explain what is going on in new_a? especially with "any(i.endswith(c)"

Comment: @learner101 Please see my recent edit. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interactive demonstration of one approach:

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 29 2016, 14:57:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d1 = ['tyuri:12345', 'hsksfd:58380', 'shskfks:49539']
>>> d1
['tyuri:12345', 'hsksfd:58380', 'shskfks:49539']
>>> d2 = ['12345', '442342', '8053308']
>>> d2
['12345', '442342', '8053308']
>>> m1 = dict(map(lambda x:(x.split(":")[1],x),d1))
>>> m1
{'49539': 'shskfks:49539', '58380': 'hsksfd:58380', '12345': 'tyuri:12345'}
>>> for v in d2:
...     if v in m1:
...         print(m1[v])
... 
tyuri:12345
```